# Date/Time Field Django Models

Tags: django, django-models

I am looking for some help on a appointment booking system i am building. Basically when creating my models i only want my user to be able to select week days & specific hours.

Is this possible with django models.

Here is my code

```
class Appointment(models.Model):
    appointmentUser = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="appointmentfor")
    attendee = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    apointmentDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

Comment: An `auto_now` will not appear in a `ModelForm`, and will set the object to the last modification timestamp.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the DATE_INPUT_FORMATS in settings file as specified in Django documentation [DJANGO SETTINGS FILE](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/settings/)

DATETIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d']